# Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route as Route because the name is already in use in /home/laravel/routes/web.php on line 3

Tags: php, laravel

can you tell me what error is this?

```
 Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route as Route because the name is already in use in /home/laravel/routes/web.php on line 3
```

thanks for the help you can give me

Comment: In top of web.php you initiate a class with Route name and Route is defined before init it.
Share code if you want better help (web.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route` alias was inject by service container in web.php file.No need to import it on top.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route as Route;  // no need to use this line

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```